# How can i create a JButton?

Tags: java, jbutton

After creating the JButton and setting it to Visible I do not understand why I don't see it in the Window.. :/

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends JFrame{

    public static int width = 350;
    public static int height  = 480;

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(width, height);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setTitle("Virtual World");
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(80,80,240));

        JButton enter = new JButton();
        enter.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: You need to add the button to the content pane of the JFrame.

Comment: `window.add(enter)` You havent added the button to the JFrame.

Comment: Components don't appear just by setting them to visible. As earlier answers indicate, you have to add them to a container, in your case JFrame - window.

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tunaki already mentioned in the comment,you need to add your JButton to the Panel first.

Try this

```
public class Test extends JFrame{

    public static int width = 350;
    public static int height  = 480;

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(width, height);

        window.setTitle("Virtual World");
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(80,80,240));

        JButton enter = new JButton("Ok");
        enter.setVisible(true);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        window.add(panel);
        panel.add(enter);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

You need to add a `JPanel` in your `JFrame`.You can then add your `JButton` to the `JPanel`.

Comment: Components should be added to the frame before the frame is made visible. Class names should start with an upper case character.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for pointing out :) Made changes as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to add the following line in the end of your code:

```
window.getContentPane().add( enter );
```

This will add a button to the content panel of you JFrame.
But note that you will end up with a button of the size of your window ;)

Comment: Yes my button is the Size of my window and when I do enter.setSize(50, 50); Nothing happens...